# XSLT Grouping tokenized values by condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm having difficulty grouping the repeating elements to a new xml.

My input file is

```
<Load>
    <DataArea>
        <tag>
            <row>A,Header</row>
        </tag>

        <tag>
            <row>B,20190701</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>C,12345, 100.00, 200.00</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>D,001, 25.00</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>D,002, 35.00</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>D,003, 45.00</row>
        </tag>

        <tag>
            <row>B,20190702</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>C,12345, 300.00, 400.00</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>D,004, 55.00</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>D,005, 65.00</row>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <row>D,006, 75.00</row>
        </tag>

    </DataArea>
</Load>
```

I have to tokenize the comma separated element values and want to transform it to the xml structure below.

```
<Load>
    <DataArea>
        <Header>
            <A>Header</A>
        </Header>

        <Line>
            <!-- July 1 Record -->
            <B>20190701</B>
            <C>12345</C>
            <D>
                <code>001</code>
                <amount>25.00</amount>
            </D>
            <D>
                <code>002</code>
                <amount>35.00</amount>
            </D>
            <D>
                <code>003</code>
                <amount>45.00</amount>
            </D>
        </Line>

        <Line>
            <!-- July 2 Record -->
            <B>20190702</B>
            <C>12345</C>
            <D>
                <code>004</code>
                <amount>55.00</amount>
            </D>
            <D>
                <code>005</code>
                <amount>65.00</amount>
            </D>
            <D>
                <code>006</code>
                <amount>75.00</amount>
            </D>
        </Line>
    </DataArea>
</Load>
```

There are 2 `<Lines></Lines>` because there are only two dates **July 1** and **July 2**. Dates are represented as value for element `<B>`

There are multiple `<D>`'s for every `<Line>`

My problem is I couldn't group `<B><C>` and `<D>`'s together enclosed by `<Line>`. The `<D>`'s should belong to the right `<B>` or date.

Below is my xslt code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Load>
            <DataArea>
                <Header>
                    <A>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Load/DataArea/tag">
                            <xsl:variable name="col"
                                select="tokenize(current(),',')" />
                            <xsl:if test="$col[1] = 'A' ">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$col[2]" />
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </A>
                </Header>

                <xsl:for-each select="Load/DataArea/tag">
                    <xsl:variable name="column"
                        select="tokenize(current(),',')" />
                    <Line>
                        <xsl:if test="$column[1] = 'B' ">
                            <B>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$column[2]" />
                            </B>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$column[1] = 'C' ">
                            <C>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$column[2]" />
                            </C>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:for-each select="../tag">
                            <xsl:variable name="column"
                                select="tokenize(current(),',')" />
                            <xsl:if test="$column[1] = 'D' ">
                                <D>
                                    <code>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$column[2]" />
                                    </code>
                                    <amount>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$column[3]" />
                                    </amount>
                                </D>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Line>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </DataArea>
        </Load>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting all `<D>`'s per loop instead of just those that belong to the Date/`<B>` Repeats all `<D>`'s and `<Line>`

I'm not sure how to solve this especially that I need to tokenize them.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be a job for `xsl:for-each-group` with the `group-starting-with` attribute.

Try this XSLT, which I have also simplified around getting the `A` header using basic `starts-with` functionality

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Load>
      <DataArea>
        <Header>
          <A>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Load/DataArea/tag[starts-with(row, 'A,')], ',') " />
          </A>
        </Header>          
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Load/DataArea/tag[not(starts-with(row, 'A,'))]" group-starting-with="tag[starts-with(row, 'B,')]">
          <Line>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:variable name="column" select="tokenize(row,',')" />
              <xsl:element name="{$column[1]}">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$column[1] = 'B' or $column[1] = 'C'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$column[2]" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <code>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$column[2]" />
                  </code>
                  <amount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$column[3]" />
                  </amount>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Line>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </DataArea>
    </Load>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim. I haven't used and not familiar with some of the functions you used here. I'll spend some time studying them. This solved my problem. I appreciate the help. This will help me learn XSLT better.

Comment: I replaced 'A' with '01' but I get an error with QName is not valid. `substring-after(Load/DataArea/tag[starts-with(row, 'A,')], ',')` would you know why?

Comment: It's probably failing on this line; `<xsl:element name="{$column[1]}">`, where it dynamically creates a new element based on the first value, and `<01>` is not a valid name for an element. Did you change all occurrences of "A" in there XSLT too? For example, the `xsl:for-each-group` needs to become `<xsl:for-each-group select="Load/DataArea/tag[not(starts-with(row, '01,'))]"`. Thanks!

Comment: Or perhaps you also replaced "B" with "02" and "C" with "03" etc.... If so, you would need to do extra work to handle the creation of the element. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7nd for one example on how to do this.